# using radio within angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to use radio button in angular application. But it selecting all radio buttons. I can do something on selected.

```
angular.module('radioApp', [])
    .controller('AppController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.colors = [
            {id:1, name:"red"},
            {id:2, name:"blue"},
            {id:3, name:"green"}];

        $scope.colorSelect = function(color){
            alert(color.name)
        }
    }]);
```

HTML code is here

```
<div ng-app="radioApp">
    <div ng-controller="AppController">
        <div ng-repeat="color in colors">
            <input type="radio"  ng-value="id"/>  {{color.name}} <br/>
        </div>
      <tt>color = {{color | json}}</tt><br/>
    </div>    
</div>
```

Working code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/barteloma/4zsqsbe1/).

Comment: try saying this `<input type="radio" name="color"  ng-value="id"/>  {{color.name}} <br/>` add a  fixed `name` attribute to radios.

Comment: updated the answer with a working fiddle contains what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think adding a fixed `name` attribute will work here. Because HTML recognize radios of same group by their name

say like bellow

```
<input type="radio" name="color"  ng-value="id"/>  {{color.name}} <br/>
```

**(radio buttons with the same name belong to the same group)**

This should solve your problem

```
<div ng-app="radioApp">
    <div ng-controller="AppController">
        <div ng-repeat="color in colors">
            <input type="radio" name="color"  ng-value="id" ng-click="colorSelect(color)"/>  {{color.name}} <br/>
        </div>
      <tt>color = {{color.name}}</tt><br/>
    </div>    
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module('radioApp', [])
    .controller('AppController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.colors = [
            {id:1, name:"red"},
            {id:2, name:"blue"},
            {id:3, name:"green"}];
        $scope.color=$scope.colors[0];

        $scope.colorSelect = function(color){
            alert(color.name)
            $scope.color=color
        }
    }]);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4zsqsbe1/4/)

Comment: "radio buttons with the same name belong to the same group" is great description thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-app="radioApp">
    <div ng-controller="AppController">
        <div ng-repeat="color in colors">
            <input type="radio" name="color" ng-value="id"/>  {{color.name}} <br/>
        </div>
      <tt>color = {{color | json}}</tt><br/>
    </div>    
</div>`enter code here`
```

add a name :)